# reading rows of specified values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

hi so i have a spread sheet and i managed to read it without using google Api
Using pandas and python, but i want to read the rows of a specified value  without reading the whole spreadsheet because if i had a large DB reading the whole spreadsheet then searching inside the whole DB will take a long time so what i want is, for example if this is the spread sheet in a csv format

```
id   name    age
0    alex    12
1    sam     26
2    fay     21
```

i want to get the rows where the value of age = 26 and the result should be like this:

```
id  name  age
1   sam   26
```

i managed to import certain rows from the spread sheet but i couldn't get the the rows based on a "where" statement
i'm a beginner at using Pandas so please help me if you can,here is the code

```
import pandas as pd

sheetId = "the sheet id is here"
sheetname = "Sheet1"
url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{}/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv&sheet={}".format(sheetId, sheetname)
DATA = pd.read_csv(url,usecols=[1])
print(DATA)
```

in here i managed to read a specified row directly from the spread sheet , here is the result of the code above:

```
NAME
alex
sam
fay
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple filter operation in pandas :) fyi probably best to keep the data variable lowercase but just styling (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

This should work to filter the data you need. You can also use >, <, <=, >= operators! This tutorial might help you: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/intro_tutorials/03_subset_data.html

```
age_26 = DATA[DATA["age"] == 26]
```

If the data must be filtered on reads prior to entering the dataframe

```
import csv
from pandas import DataFrame

with open("spreadsheet.csv", "r") as file:
  reader = csv.DictReader(file)
  df = DataFrame([row for row in reader if row["age"] == 26])
```

Comment: you didn't understand me, i want to get data from the spread sheet directly based on a filter the same way i got the data of a certain row directly from the spread sheet, thank you.

Comment: It's not possible to filter directly through the spreadsheet using `read_csv`, you'll need to either implement a custom read method or filter in pandas (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

Comment: @quhtani I've added a version that might work for you. Ultimately you will need to read in memory. You can read the file line by line instead of the whole file at once instead if you are concerned about memory

Comment: the problem isn't about the memory but the speed, for example if i had a CSV file with 100K rows it would take a long time to read every row then filter it based on a filter

Comment: I can promise you that the initial answer I have will not cause speed issues on a moderately modern (2010 or newer) machine. Essentially all that happens in a filter operation is a for loop. Even if you were to run [print(i) for i in range(100000) if randint(1,10)>5], it would not take longer than a second or two. The underlying code of pandas is quite optimized so it may even be faster than your test for loop. That said don't just trust me, generate a large csv and test it!

Comment: ok so i've found an alternate solution first ill get the Age column only and then filter it  based on the id i got, could you tell me  if there is a way to get the whole row based on the id number?

Comment: so i've ran into a problem, i managed to get the id based on age but i don't know how to get the whole row based on the id number, could you please tell me ,thank you.